# Remote desktop from azure

Tags: azure, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2016

We want to implement a solution so our employees use only remote computer instead of physical one to store their information and work, so they can login to their work desktop even if they are in home. 
Is there any guide so we can implement that with only using azure and windows server 2016 without using any VMWare or xendesktop.

Comment: What is your need? If you want to use from home means you can use VPN to connect a VM which is running in your office. It will be very expensive to give Azure VM for all employees.

Comment: Hi Tarek What do you want your employees to do? a VDI on Azure might not be the best option for you.

Comment: I am not cenrtin how I can explain it. The thing I want every one login and see his desktop no matter what computer he use. That is the whole idea. @m

Comment: @MichaelBrown Basically that what I heared that there is a new widows   server 2016 feature that allow you to remote desktop instead of individual or multi apps and give differnet desktops for each user. The reason why that because all of my employees use the same programs so it is easy for us to make an image that has all the programs that they need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/compute/remote-desktop-services/desktop-hosting-reference-architecture) defines a set of architectural blocks for using **Remote Desktop Services (RDS)** and **Microsoft Azure virtual machines** to create multitenant, hosted Windows desktop and application services, which we call "**desktop hosting**."
About the Desktop hosting logical architecture, please refer to the [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/compute/remote-desktop-services/desktop-hosting-logical-architecture).
More information about build and deploy Remote Desktop Services deployment, refer to the [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/compute/remote-desktop-services/rds-build-and-deploy).

Comment: @Tarek Barca yes, you can use Windows server 2016 Remote Desktop Services (RDS) and Microsoft Azure Infrastucture Services, to create highly secure, scalable, and reliable desktop hosting solutions for small- and medium-sized organizations with 5 to 5000 users.

Comment: Thanks Jason. This is good start and it seems like what we need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a virtual machine using the Windows Server template and enable the Remote Desktop Services (Windows Server feature) that involves that you have to buy a CAL for each user that is going to connect. Before Azure ASM had Azure Remote Desktop but they decide to opt for another technology like you described in the question.

Update:
Now there are some products in Azure to get virtual desktops like Windows Virtual Desktop https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ua9P4VsICFM

Comment: Basically that what I heared that there is a new widows 2016 feature that allow you to remote desktop instead of individual or multi apps and give differnet desktops for each user. The reason why that because all of my employees use the same programs so it is easy for us to make an image that has all the programs that they need.

Comment: By default you can access with two different users at the same time, but when you activate Remote Desktop Services you can virtualize the desktop or some application for many as you can depending of the hardware resources Here you have a link with the steps [link](https://robertsmit.wordpress.com/2015/06/23/step-by-step-server-2016-remote-desktop-services-quickstart-deployment-rds-vdi-rdp-remoteapp/)